# C# Attributes: One Attribute to Rule Them All?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

Is it possible to assign an attribute on a property and use it in order to assign other attributes - doing so without using reflection?

The code:

```
public class CashierOut : BaseActivity
{
    [Description("Flag indicates whether break to execution.")]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    [MyCustomAttribute(ParameterGroups.Extended)]
    public bool CancelExecution { get; set; }

    [Description("Flag indicates whether allow exit before declation.")]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    [MyCustomAttribute(ParameterGroups.Extended)]
    [DisplayName("Exit before declaration?")]
    public bool AllowExitBeforeDeclare { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
public class CashierOut : BaseActivity
{
    [MyResourceCustom("CashierOut.CancelExecution")]
    public bool CancelExecution { get; set; }

    [MyResourceCustom("CashierOut.AllowExitBeforeDeclare")]
    public bool AllowExitBeforeDeclare { get; set; }
}

public sealed class MyResourceCustom : Attribute
{
    public string ResourcePath { get; private set; }

    public ParameterGroupAttribute(string resourcePath)
    {
        ResourcePath = resourcePath;

        // Get attributes attributes value from external resource using the path.
    }
}
```

Comment: Im pretty sure no, attributes are normally used by reflection and i dont think you could fakie it on and still have it be able to be looked up with reflection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attributes simply add meta data to the members they are defined on - by themselves they do nothing.

You will have to use reflection in order to produce some behaviour depending on the attribute values.

This is how all attributes work - some of the tooling is aware of some attributes (like the compiler and the `ConditionalAttribute`), but this is still done via reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Look into Aspect Oriented Programming. You can use tools like [postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) to modify your code either at compile or runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a member to `MyResourceCustom` that wraps Description, DefaultValue, and MyCustomAttribute in an immutable instance (maybe even a static global, if it can be the same for everyone).

```
public class MyResourceCustom : Attribute {
  public MyResourceCustomDescriptor Descriptor { get; private set; }
  public MyResourceCustom(MyResourceCustomDescriptor descriptor)
  : base() {
    Descriptor = descriptor;
  }

public class MyResourceCustomDescriptor {
  public string          Description    { get; private set; }
  public bool            DefaultValue   { get; private set; }
  public ParameterGroups ParameterGroup { get; private set; }

  public MyResourceCustomDescriptor(string path) {
    // read from path
  }
}

public class MyAdvancedResouceCustomDescriptor : MyResourceCustomDescriptor {
  public string DisplayName { get; private set; }
  // etc...
}
```

When you fetch the attribute you can get its `Descriptor` property and read the values.

As a sidenote, you should name it `IsDefaultValue`.